# Sending sms for two factor authentication from google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, sms

I am trying to send sms from google app engine. My service provider has provided me with sms gateway api and key.

I have found how i can use twilo but that is not helpful as twilo has its own sdk.

Any pointers how i can go about this?

Comment: If possible you should provide post what code have you done or at least a link to  a documentation from your service provider

Answer (score 0):

Use [URL Fetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/issue-requests) to make manual POST request to your SMS gateway API.